# Is ng-content a component? How is it implemented?

Tags: angular

In angular 2 components have their own scope so the binding context of any data bindings in their templates are the components themselves. NG2 has no notion of outside binding context (aka $scope in ng1, datacontext in xaml, bindingcontext in aurelia/knockout, etc...) which is bad and weird but not the focus of this question. My question is how is ng-content implemented?

Say child component has the following template:

```
<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>
```

Say parent component has the following template:

```
<child><input [(ngModel)]="name"></child>
```

And say both parent and child have a "name" property...

If I understand things correctly, at runtime the binding context of the input element will be parent, not child, despite the fact that parent's content was transposed to child... How is this achieved? I have a child component that uses DynamicComponentLoad to dynamically insert content, not coming from the parent, into itself and needs the binding context to remain being the parent? Anyone have any ideas? Does anyone have any clues how ng-content makes this work? I understand how input bindings work and I understand how services work... But neither of these is what I am looking for... In my component I am going to dynamically add content but I need the binding context of this content to be the outside component...

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not a component. It's `ast`(Abstract Syntax Tree) node within compiler (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/template_ast.ts#L197) and  it is compiled using `visitNgContent` method https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/view_builder.ts#L135

Comment: `<ng-content>` just inserts the transcluded HTML at the position where the `<ng-content>` tag was added. Otherwise there is nothing special. The binding happens with the context where the HTML was added, no matter if the HTML was wrapped in an element that has an `<ng-content>` or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the child context, you need to leverage templates like this:

```
<child>
  <template let-name>
    <input [(ngModel)]="name">
  </template>
</child>
```

In this case, don't use `ng-content` but crate an embedded view like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div #target></div>
  `
})
export class Child Components  {
  name: string = 'some value';

  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef;

  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let viewRef = this.target.createEmbeddedView(this.template, {
      $implicit: this.name
    });
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

In this case, the properties of the child component are used instead of the parent ones.

A shortcut would be to reference the child component with a local variable and use it to get its property values:

```
<child #c>
  <input [(ngModel)]="c.name">
</child>
```

Comment: thank you very much thierry templier... but I need to do a better job of asking the question...